# Mapbox Geocoder with a Leaflet map. Zoom to result, how?

Tags: leaflet, geocoding, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a Lealfet map together with the Mapbox geocoder outside the map. The Geocoder and the map works. But i need to zoom to the result from the geocoder.

Some code:

```
          var map = L.map('map').setView([35.936050, 10.541736], 5);


          var tiles = L.tileLayer('http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.png', {
                maxZoom: 18,
                attribution: 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
            }).addTo(map);


          var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
           accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
           mapboxgl: mapboxgl,
           marker: false
           });
```

It just zooms into a random place, when i click a result from the dropdown. In below Example it zooms to a place just outside Somalia

[image]

Map result:

[image]

Can I somehow log the result from the geocoder, so i can see the data?

Comment: If you take Amsterdam coordinates lng,lat [52.35, 4.90] and exchange coordinates to [4.90, 52.35], you end up in the sea outside Somalia. Leaflet uses [lat,lng] coordinate order and it seems that Mapboxgeocoder uses [lng,lat] order.

Comment: I wonder how you managed to mix Leaflet with the Mapbox geocoder (which is meant for mapbox GLJS and not meant for Leaflet). It's not a standard integration AFAIK.

Comment: @TomazicM Thanks. Of course! I feel stupid after this..... But it got me on track, somehow, together with the answer here, [Mapbox use point result from Geocoding/Search.......](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/337854/mapbox-use-point-result-from-geocoding-search-to-queryrenderedfeatures-on-polygo) .

Answer (score 1):

I solved this based on this [mapbox use point result from geocoding](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/337854/mapbox-use-point-result-from-geocoding-search-to-queryrenderedfeatures-on-polygo) together with the comment from @TomazicM.

1. get the bbox from the geocoder result:

   `var geocoder_result = e.result.bbox;`
2. Use fitbounds to fit the map the the bbox:

```
      map.fitBounds([
        [e.result.bbox[3], e.result.bbox[0]],
        [e.result.bbox[1], e.result.bbox[2]]
      ])
```

@IvanSanchez
Im using the mapbox geocoder "without" a map: [Use the geocoder without a map](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-geocoder-no-map/). Then I use the above method to get the result of the geocoder to be used in my Leaflet map.